# C Programming Math Functions #include <stdlib.h> abs()

Tags: c

I start learing C programming from "Beginning Programming with C For Dummies" by Dan Gookin.
I have a problem with understanding "C Math Functions" - my question is how to use `#include <stdlib.h>` and `abs()` function. Only explanation in the book is this:

[image]

Comment: It strikes me as unhelpful that the list shows `abs()` for integers without mentioning `fabs()` from `<math.h>` for `double`.

Comment: One thing I will say is if you are beginning your coding process look into better material than one of those ***'For Dummies' Books. Yeah they may seem as if they will help, but they may just yield some oversimplifications to some concepts that could mess you up in your path to programming. I'd recommend looking into the K&R Bible, yes that's the quickest way to get to it, and reading that. It highlights a lot of concepts that will help you understand what is going on underneath it all, which is where you will be living until you get past the C language as it's very, do it all yourself type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides the examples given above,functions work just like a mathematical function 
in that y = f(x) you put in x and it returns a y(of course some dont return anything and some dont take in anything)

now what you need to do is to catch that value when it returns it by storing it into some memory location which is called a variable that you declare

its also important that you know what the return type is so that you dont truncate or lose some part of the result

for example if the result is a floating point number then you need to return the value into a float/double variable and if it is a integer you can store it in either int or double/float

also if it is a char you would probably want it to be returned to a char variable and so on and so forth

So any function that you write or that you use from somebody elses library/header is going to work like that

It takes in an argument(sometimes it can even take no arguments and you just use it by calling it with parentheses, parentheses must always be typed because otherwise it will look like a variable or something else and convention says so) and it returns some result(if it does return a result) or does something else unrelated to the calling functions variables/values

So hopefully that explains what functions are, and how you can use them

Now all of this described also applies to the functions you posted about, they have a set algorithm that they do which somebody else wrote, and you just give it the argument, and catch the return type and it will do what it says it intended to do i.e abs() gives you the absolute value, pow() returns the square of some base and so on

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i = -42;
    int j = abs(i);
    printf("i = %d, j = %d\n", i, j);
    return 0;
}
```

<kbd>[LIVE DEMO](http://ideone.com/dNoHdZ)</kbd>

Comment: +1 For that demo, and the functionality of IDEone to show library definitions from opengroup is something that I didn't know about. Going to test that out for a few other languages, and see if it will allow the use of system calls within it soon.

Answer (score 0):

The line `#include <stdlib.h>` gives your code access to certain functions and abilities that are within that library. One of which is the `abs()` function.

The `abs()` function return the **absolute** value of an integer, by that we mean it will always convert it to a positive number.

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>      /* printf */
#include <stdlib.h>     /* abs */

int main ()
{
  int n,m;
  n=abs(23);
  m=abs(-11);
  printf ("n=%d\n",n);
  printf ("m=%d\n",m);
  return 0;
}
```

Edit & Run

```
Output:

n=23
m=11
```

Comment: Note that `<stdlib.h>` is a header, not a library.  The functions declared in the header are provided by the library, but it is the same library that provides the functions declared in the other standard headers (and, usually, a bunch of functions defined in a collection of non-standard headers).